# Is sagotra vivah lawful with exceptions?

Tags: dharma-shastras, manu-smriti, parashara-smriti

Is this true that a couple of same gotra can marry if they have different shasana or this a misconception developed in masses these days ?
If yes, what does this term shasana mean ? Please share the reference.

Comment: Is anyone aware of it ? Please suggest 